# Group Columns by day in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, multiple-columns

I'm working on a Column chart is struggling to visualize the data as shown in this graph:
[image]

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Day', 'Amount'],
     ['Mon', 4],
     ['Mon', 6],
     ['Tue', 3],
     ['Wed', 3],
 ]);
```

Not like this graph:

[image]

Is it possible in Google Charts to group data so that data with the same day is displayed next to each other in the xAxis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to group on the x-axis, add columns / additional series...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Day', 'Amount 1', 'Amount 2'],
  ['Mon', 4, 6],
  ['Tue', 3, null],
  ['Wed', 3, null]
]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Amount 1', 'Amount 2'],
    ['Mon', 4, 6],
    ['Tue', 3, null],
    ['Wed', 3, null]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hey WhiteHat. It helps somewhat, but a problem is that I do not necessarily know the number of 'Amount 1', 'Amount 2', 'Amount #', etc.. each day will have. So I'm not sure if I can hardcode it like your suggestion.

But it could work, I could set up a limit that only show max 5 or so columns for each day and work from there, but it's not optimal. Thank you very much though!

Comment: just an example of the data table format needed, it doesn't have to be hard-coded, you could use the [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method to know how many columns to add...